# How to move mysql data to Hive using sqoop2

Tags: hive, sqoop

I have successfully installed and data imported from MySql to the HDFS but I couldn't get the 
data in the Hive. the corresponding data imported from the Mysql is found in Hdfs as comma separated format.

Older versions of sqoop using

`sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://remote-ip/db --username xxx --password xxx --table tb --hive-import --hive-table foo.tb`

In Sqoop2 i couldn't find an option to set the hive table options while creating the job or connectors

Please help...

Comment: have you tried googling it. The first result with your question heading gave me this http://gethue.tumblr.com/post/66348238493/hadoop-tutorials-series-ii-8-how-to-transfer-data

Comment: yeah.. i can move data to HDFS. but how do we specify a Hive table [if its not present create the table] in the cluster?
in older version of sqoop we can import using
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://remote-ip/db --username xxx --password xxx --table tb --hive-import --hive-table foo.tb

but i couldn't get a way to do the same in "sqoop2"!

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/EMR_Interactive_Hive.html

Comment: its Amazon's EMR service. An application of map reduce using Hive. Im trying to move data to hive table so its not gonna help me :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sqoop2 currently do not have integration with Hive and can import data only to HDFS. You can load them into Hive manually from there though (using LOAD DATA command). Or you can continue using Sqoop1 for the time being.